# Monotouch: 5.1.0 Beta API change in CheckVersion

Tags: xamarin.ios, backwards-compatibility, version-compatibility

In Beta 5.1 of MonoTouch the API to check version changed, it is returning an `int` now.

```
UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(5,0,0);
```

I can't find out what the `int` mean though. Before it was a `bool`.

Comment: Just noticed the same thing myself.  Xamarin, what's up?  It's returning a 0 for @Bahai's code in the 5.0 simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a mistake and it's noted in the 5.1 [release notes](http://ios.xamarin.com/Releases/MonoTouch_5/MonoTouch_5.1/Beta_5.1_Changes):

> This is a temporary regression in the Beta, it will be reverted back to the 5.0 signature on the next release.

The idea behind the `int` version was to enable code to do things like:

```
if (CheckSystemVersion (5, 0, 1) >= 0) { // set backup bit }
```

Comment: How do I revert to MonoTouch 5.0?

Comment: Remove (or better/safer rename) your `/Developer/MonoTouch/` directory and re-install MonoTouch 5.0. If you need to download it again then go the the support portal (http://support.xamarin.com/) and look for "Product Download and Activation Self Service"